# MYSQL - set default as NULL to all columns, where default is not set

Tags: mysql, cleardb

I have about 12 databases, each with 50 tables and most of them with 30+ columns; the db was running in strict mode as OFF, but now we had to migrate the db to cleardb service which by default has strict mode as ON.
all the tables that had "Not Null" constraint, the inserts have stopped working, just because the default values are not being passed; while in case of strict mode as OFF if the value are not provided, the MYSQL will presume the default value of the column datatype. 
Is there a script I can use to get the metadata about all the columns of all tables and generate a script to alter all the tables with such columns to change the default to "Null"

Comment: Asking for any off-site resource is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I am not asking for any off site resource @Shadow  I am looking for guidance on how to do it, not that I am sitting here twiddling my thumbs, while someone helps me.

Comment: Moreover, setting the default field value to null on fields that are defined as not null is probably not the best idea. Your question implies that you are looking for a complete existing solution. ("Is there a script..."). You have not demonstrated any effort in solving the question, therefore it is unlikely that your question will fly in its current format.

Comment: which is right, but sometimes one has to work with what is given; the person designing this db probably didn't gave a thought about the strict mode. Setting Not Null and not providing any value sounds crazy already.

Comment: You did not get my point: if a field has a `not null` restriction and then you set its default value to null, then the 2 settings will contradict each other.

Comment: and I get that, that's what I want to change, the columns with "Not Null" constraint be given a default value accordingly or remove Not Null from such columns at all, may be I wasn't as clear in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the `information_schema` tables to generate DDL statements to alter the tables.  This kind of query will get you the list of offending columns.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.',TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) col  
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 0
   AND LENGTH(COLUMN_DEFAULT) = 0 
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('db1', 'db2', 'db3')
```

You can do similar things to generate `ALTER` statements to change the tables. But beware, MySQL likes to rewrite tables when you alter certain things. It might take time.

**DO NOT** attempt to `UPDATE` the information_schema directly!

You could try changing the strict_mode setting when you connect to the SaaS service, so your software will work compatibly.

This is a large project and is probably important business for cleardb. Why not ask them for help in changing the strict_mode setting?

Comment: information schema idea is good, I am working on the same lines, Cleardb won't do it for me, unless we switch to the dedicated servers.

Comment: Tell cleardb you're going to AWS, Rackspace, or Azure if they don't help you. Migrating to cloud services is hard enough without having to gratuitously change your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with on the base of @Ollie-jones script

https://gist.github.com/brijrajsingh/efd3c273440dfebcb99a62119af2ecd5

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.',TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) col,CONCAT('alter table ',TABLE_NAME,' MODIFY COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME,' ',DATA_TYPE,'(',CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,') NULL DEFAULT NULL') as script_col
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE is_nullable=0 
 and length(COLUMN_DEFAULT) is NULL and
 CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is not NULL and 
 table_schema = 'immh' 
 Union
 SELECT CONCAT_WS('.',TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) col,CONCAT('alter table ',TABLE_NAME,' MODIFY COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME,' ',DATA_TYPE,' NULL DEFAULT NULL') as script_col
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE is_nullable=0 
 and length(COLUMN_DEFAULT) is NULL and
 CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is NULL and 
 table_schema = 'immh'
```